# UseHTML=True in legend ignores itemWidth on click

Tags: highcharts, formatting, pie-chart

Then again, here I am struggling to work with the plot of pie charts.

When I use useHTML as true it renders exactly as I want (respecting itemWidth too), but when I click in the legend it stops respecting itemWidth and the items overlap. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVyEL/17/)
Code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            height: 660, 
            width: 400,
        },

        title: {        
                text: 'Example',
            },

        plotOptions: {
             pie: {
                center: [200, 50],
                size: '150',
                innerSize: '75%',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }

        },

        legend: {
            useHTML:true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            floating: true,
            itemWidth: 180,
            y: 200,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize:'12px',
                fontWeight: 'light',
                width: 160
                }
            },

        series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: [['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',0.0516218483578],['bbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ',0.257286564668],['cccccccccccccccccc',1.12221284311],['dddddddd ddddddddd',1.1265250728],['rrrrrrr rrrrrrrrrrr',0.17346294958],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa ',1.20890386677],['ffffffff ',0.459460369787],['gfdgdfgdfg  ',6.13592008543],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa ',0.395214054153],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',0.366061664716],['dddddddddd',0.149098291043],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',0.0957028394272],['tttttttttttt ',3.48603058953],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',1.6316529146],['fdsfsdfsd .',1.34404210477],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',0.350541259163],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaas ',0.45563482302],['gdffdgdgg ',0.601007305701],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',1.07655357912],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa ',0.145888955634],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa',13.0487584317],['dasdasfsafsaf',1.79394965159],['Vesdfsdrde  ',3.41252042196],['Aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa ',0.258638673662],],
              }]
    });              
});
```

How can I keep the formatting even after clicking in the legend?

Comment: Looks like a bug, reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4260). Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Well,I guess I'll have to wait. Thanks, Sebastian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the bug was solved in the recent releases.